# Docker daemon and DNS

Tags: dns, docker

I am trying to force the docker daemon to use my DNS server which is binded to bridge0 interface.
I have added --dns 172.17.42.1 in my docker_opts but no success

DNS server reply ok with dig command:

```
dig @172.17.42.1 registry.service.consul SRV +short
1 1 5000 registry2.node.staging.consul.
```

But pull with this domain fails:

```
docker pull registry.service.consul:5000/test
FATA[0000] Error: issecure: could not resolve "registry.service.consul": lookup registry.service.consul: no such host
```

PS: By adding nameserver 172.17.42.1 in my /etc/resolv.conf solve the issue but the DNS has to be exclusively for docker commands.

Any idea ?

Comment: in general you are trying to override a dns resolution for any command.  i don't think you can do this without either updating the /etc/resolv.conf or /etc/hosts. one thing that might work is to run a docker registry cache, and point its dns to your dns server when doing the run of the registry.  you would then have to use that cache for all of your pull requests. https://github.com/docker/docker-registry

Comment: When you docker --help, as fas as I can see, I should be able to do: docker --dns=172.17.42.1 pull registry.service.consul/xxx

Comment: I tried that.  I put a monitor on tcpdump and did the --dns on the pull, but, there were no requests going to the --dns address.  I looked at the documentation and it seems that --dns can be used with run, and that's it.

Comment: Ok thanks for checking greg. If anyone have an idea, it would be nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You passed `--dns 172.17.42.1` to docker_opts, so since that you should be able to resolve the container hostnames from inside other containers. **But** obviously you're doing `docker pull` from the host, not from the container, isn't it? Therefore it's not surprising that you cannot resolve container's hostname from your host, because it is not configured to use `172.17.42.1` for resolving.

I see two possible solutions here:

1. Force your host to use `172.17.42.1` as DNS (`/etc/resolv.conf` etc).
2. Create a special container with Docker client inside and mount `docker.sock` inside it. This will make you able to use all client commands including `pull`:

   `docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw --name=client ...`

   `docker exec -it client docker pull registry.service.consul:5000/test`

Comment: Ok so you confirm --dns options is only used for container purposes in order to set the IP provided in the container's resolv.conf

Comment: @FlorentValdelievre, I do :)