# Docker daemon flags ignored

Tags: ubuntu, docker, debian

## Environment:

- **OS**: debian 8.0.0-amd64, ubuntu-15.04, 16.04
- **Docker**: 1.x.x

## Procedure:

I changed `/etc/default/docker` to add a private docker registry, then I restarted docker service and finally tried to pull some image.

```
$ cat /etc/default/docker
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry mydocker-registry.net:5000"

$ service docker restart

$ docker pull mydocker-registry.net:5000/testdb
FATA[0000] Error: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://mydocker-
registry.net:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup mydocker-registry.net: no 
such host. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an 
unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry mydocker-
registry.net:5000` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if 
you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; 
simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/mydocker-
registry.net:5000/ca.crt
```

A `ps` output shows nothing about DOCKER_OPTS environment var.

```
$ ps auxwww|grep docker
root  6919   0.0   0.1   331076   19984 ? Ssl 10:14   0:00 /usr/bin/docker -d -H fd://
```

## Question:

According to docker documentation the way to use a private registry is through DOCKER_OPTS in `/etc/default/docker`. Why, after doing that, it does not take effect in this environment?

## Notes:

- The private registry hostname is correctly resolved by the DNS.

Comment: Your docker daemon is unable to find your private registry - does it in fact exist and can be found in dns? `dial tcp: lookup mydocker-registry.net: no such host`

Comment: Did you restart docker after changing `/etc/default/docker`?

Comment: Can you try and add a `--dns` option to your `DOCKER_OPTS`? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/29607761/6309)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

## Recommended Way Docker 17.xx +

There are a number of ways to configure the daemon flags and environment variables for your Docker daemon. The [recommended way](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd//#daemon-configuration-file) is to use the platform-independent `daemon.json` file, which is located in `/etc/docker/` on Linux by default.

So, for configuring insecure registries, do the following:

1. Set the following flag in the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file:

   ```
   {
       "insecure-registries": ["mydocker-registry.net:5000"]
   }
   ```
2. Restart Docker

   ```
    $ sudo systemctl restart docker
   ```

Easier each time!

---

## Previously Recommended Way with Docker 1.12

According to [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/), The recommended way  to configure the daemon flags and environment variables for your Docker daemon is to use a **systemd** *drop-in file*.

So, for this specific case, do the following:

1. Create a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/private-registry.conf` with the following content:

   > If not exists, create directory `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`

   ```
   [Service]
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --insecure-registry mydocker-registry.net:5000
   ```
2. Flush changes:

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
3. Restart Docker:

   ```
    $ sudo systemctl restart docker
   ```

Voila!

---

## Not recommended way

Edit file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

```
...
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
...
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker
...
```

Then execute

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Verify that `/etc/default/docker` is loaded

```
ps auxwww | grep docker
root      4989  0.8  0.1 265540 16608 ?        Ssl  10:37   0:00 /usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// --insecure-registry
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks, I was having this issue too, and this fixed it! Do you know if this is going to be fixed in later versions of docker (im assuming this is a packaging issue), maybe someone should submit a bug report.

Comment: Shouldn't `EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker` be `EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/docker`?

Comment: @Leonti, the suggested changes are based on the examples here: https://docs.docker.com/articles/systemd/

Comment: Make sure your *EnvironmentFile* (`/etc/default/docker` here) file only contains *KEY=VALUE* pairs (no *#* comments)

Answer (score 8):

Things seem to have changed in `Ubuntu 16.04` using docker `1.12.x`. Based on the updated [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/)

Add `DOCKER_OPTS="-g /mnt/somewhere/else/docker/ --storage-driver=overlay2"` to `/etc/default/docker`

Edit file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

```
...
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
...
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker
...
```

Then execute:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: The question is about how to achieve `DOCKER_OPT` values were not ignored, not about how to change Docker's storage base directory (where container and images go). The rest of the post is exactly equal to the accepted answer

Comment: This helped me. In my Ubuntu installation, the file that was being used was /lib/systemd/system/docker.service, and so I had the symptom that the docker config file specified in most documentation had no effect.

Answer (score 6):

Systemd based systems do not read /etc/default configurations, you have to put those in /etc/systemd now, see also docker bug [docker bug #12926](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12926)

There is an official documentation on the Docker site now, refer to [Control and configure Docker with systemd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/).

You should never directly hack the service files for configuration.

Tested and works on Arch and Debian based systems - I had to include the option to ignore any obsolete EnvironmentFile directives, though (see also linked Docker reference, but I didn't spot it at first and thought it was not needed):

```
-EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/docker
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Systemd is really not designed for *appending* options to ExecStart or Environment. The best and also most platform-independent way is to use the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` [configuration file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#/daemon-configuration-file).

Behold:

```
cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json <<DOCKERCONFIG
{
  "labels": ["foo=bar"],
  "insecure-registries": ["mydocker-registry.net:5000"]
}
DOCKERCONFIG
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ubuntu specific solution to insecure-registry via DOCKER_OPTS

Because...

```
$ dpkg --list | grep -i docker
ii  docker.io                          1.12.3-0ubuntu4~16.04.2            amd64        Linux container runtime
```

...ships with...

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
# Uncomment TasksMax if your systemd version supports it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this version.
TasksMax=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes
# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

...(Specifically: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS`) you can do a hybrid approach combining the [[chosen answer's]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30127580/117471) "[Recommended Way](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#/custom-docker-daemon-options)" and the use of `DOCKER_OPTS` to keep from blowing over the `-H fd://` option if you were to redefine `ExecStart`

```
# The docker.io package doesn't create a systemd drop-ins directory, so we will
$ mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
$ cat > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-insecure-registry.conf <<EOF
[Service]
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry docker.internal:5000"
EOF
```

Comment: 4. mar 2017, docker version 17.03.0-ce: I had to add `$DOCKER_OPTS` to  `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://` in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service` manually to get this to work. Confirmed working now however.

Comment: @YngvarKristiansen interesting. What version of Ubuntu and how was Docker installed?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, kernel 4.6.0-040600-generic. I previously had Docker 1.12 installed. Then downloaded and installed using instructions here: https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-server-ubuntu?tab=description

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar challenge.  When I started looking to begin moving some systems from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.  My goal was to use one dockerd configuration file with dockerd flags (DOCKER_OPTS) for both Ubuntu 16.04 (systemd) and Ubuntu 14.04 (Upstart) other than /etc/docker/daemon.json.  I chose not to use /etc/docker/daemon.json for docker daemon configuration because json does not support comments.

I wanted a systemd design to use an override file, which only modifies dockerd flags.  It uses the default Docker systemd configuration file (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service) for other Docker settings.  Another objective was to customise systemd on each system after each change or boot.

It solves my challenge. It may help you.

https://github.com/BradleyA/docker-security-infrastructure/tree/master/dockerd-configuration-options

```
git clone https://github.com/BradleyA/docker-scripts
cd docker-scripts/dockerd-configuration-options
```