# How to connect to a remote Jupyter Notebook running on a docker container?

Tags: docker, ssh, jupyter-notebook, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am running a Jupyter-notebook on a docker container (ubuntu) running on a remote machine (amazon p2). 
I want to access the notebook via my browser (http://localhost:8883/) but am getting:

```
open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

My ssh confing:

```
Host p3
    HostName <remote machine ip>
    User <user>
    LocalForward 8883 127.0.0.1:8884
```

I am running the container (on the remote machine) with:

```
nvidia-docker run -it -p 8884:8884 <docker image>
```

And on the docker container I'm running:

```
jupyter-notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000000 --no-browser --port=8884 --allow-root
```

I'm able to connect to the notebook running on the remote machine (not in the docker container).

How can I connect to the notebook running on the docker machine from my browser?

Comment: Maybe with all those forwards network traffic gets lost somewhere. After starting container on remote machine check its IP (should be in docker inspect <container_name> output. Then use this IP directly in LocalForward rule for ssh. This way you won't go trough iptables NAT on remote machine.

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent question. My day to day development workflow involves connecting to a jupyter notebook running on a docker container on a gpu accelerated server from my laptop.

There are three parts to the problem:

1. Container
2. Host
3. Remote

#### Part 1: Configuring the Container.

You need to make sure that you can ssh to your container.  I modified the Dockerfile from [Docker's sshd example.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/)  You should modify the Docker example to fit your needs; e.g. does your use case allow for you to connect as root?

I have my containers setup for [passwordless ssh](https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/).  Note you can pre-make the files needed for passwordless ssh and just copy them over to the appropriate directories when you build your image.

If you want to save yourself some typing later, I strongly recommend modifying your jupyter config file as well.

#### Part 2: Configuring the Host

I'm assuming you're running linux on the host machine.  You'll have to create a [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/).  You should only need the `--attachable` option. I like to have an entry in my `/etc/hosts` to make life easier, for example:

```
172.21.0.2  container-1 container-1
```

You will also have to modify your `/home/<user>/.ssh/config` file on your host system.

```
Host container-1
    Hostname container-1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/containers_rsa
    User root

Host tunnel-container-1
    Hostname container-1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/containers_rsa
    User root
    LocalForward 8888 localhost:8888
    LocalForward 8000 localhost:8000
```

[Don't you get sick of having to type `nvidia-docker`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726177/5083114)?  
Here is a sample `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
  {
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    },
    "graph":"/docker-files"
  }
```

#### Part 3: Configuring the Local System.

You're almost there.  You need to be able to establish an ssh tunnel to the remote system.  Example `~/.ssh/config` for a local system:

```
Host remote_host
    Hostname remote_host
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/remote_host/remote_rsa

Host tunnel-remote_host
    Hostname remote_host
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/remote_host/remote_rsa
    LocalForward 10000 localhost:8888
    LocalForward 10006 localhost:8000
```

An important note.  I have an entry in my local `/etc/hosts` for my remote host.  Your instance may not have a static ip.  So you can either modify your local `/etc/hosts` every time you spin up your instance or have a script for sshing to your remote system with all the correct `LocalForward` directives.

#### Putting it all together.

Assumes your remote instance has successfully launched and Docker is running correctly.  In addition it assumes that you have done the convenience steps I mentions.

1. SSH to remote.
2. launch docker container. Note the container name or even better specify it.
3. Connect your container to your network. e.g. `docker network connect skynet container-1`.  You can check to see if your container is attached by running `docker network inspect skynet`. Note your network will most likely be name something other then `skynet`.
4. SSH to your docker container e.g. `ssh container-1`.
5. Start your juypyter server.  `jupyter notebook &`.  I background the process so I don't have to open another session.
6. While on your remote/host, system: `ssh -N -f tunnel-container-1`.  Ok we now have an ssh tunnel from our host system to our docker container.
7. On your local system: `ssh -N -f tunnel-remote_host`.
8. On your local system navigate to `http://localhost:10000`.

If everything works you should be connected to your jupyter server and in the root directory you specified in your Dockerfile!

#### How to trouble shoot.

First of all confirm that you can launch your docker container manually with the correct run time environment.  Confirm that you can ssh and launch jupyter notebook.  Yes you won't be able to connect to it but you will know that all those pieces are working.  Next confirm that you can establish an ssh tunnel with your container from remote to container.  You can confirm the tunnel is working correctly by using `wget` to get the html for the landing page for your jupyter server.  Next check the forwarding from local to remote/host.  It took me some trial an error to get the order correct for the `LocalForward` directive.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Here is a link to a github repo that pulls all this together: https://github.com/VanBantam/one-env