# Is multiple Docker data-roots possible and how?

Tags: docker

I have one container which needs a lot of space and I want it to use a dedicated drive on my server.

This answer comprehensively explains [how to move docker data-root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726177/355942). But is it possible to have two data-roots and assign a specific container to the second one?

Answer (score 1):

You sound like you have specific container-based needs.
Thus, moving docker data-root to another location does not seem to be the suited answer here (though you may do it anyway).

What you need are "[volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)".
Wrap your image within a *docker-compose* file, and mount some container directories as volume pointing to some "host" path (outside of docker data-root). They must indeed be the directories that will request a lot of space, and point to a VG or external mounting point (*e.g.* NFS) with sufficient space !

Eg:

```
...
my-service:
  image: my-image
  volumes:
  - "/path/within/host/opt/data/tmp/:/path/within/container/cache/:rw"
  - "/path/within/host/opt/data/layers/:/path/within/container/layers/:rw"
  - "/path/within/host/opt/data/logs/:/path/within/container/logs/:rw"
```

...

(note that "*rw*" can be omitted here, since it's the default value)