# Docker doesn't see any container and imager after I changed default directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have changed the default docker folder like it is described in the topic : [How do I change the default docker container location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070113/how-do-i-change-the-default-docker-container-location):

1. stopped docker

```
sudo systemctl stop docker && systemctl stop docker.socket
```

2. modified /etc/docker/ daemon.json

```
{
   "data-root":/mnt/disk/docker"
}
```

3. copied a data from /var/lib/docker to /mnt/disk/docker

```
cp -rp /var/lib/docker /mnt/disk/docker
```

3. start the docker

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start docker
```

I can see that docker is using /mnt/disk/docker after changes but docker can't find containers and images.
I restored the docker configuration but docker can't find a containers and images in the old directory.

Does anyone have a idea what is wrong? How to restore?

Comment: can you post the result of following command ?
```docker info -f '{{ .DockerRootDir}}'```

Comment: @MichealChoudhary the result is ```/var/lib/docker```

Comment: docker is still using the old directory

Comment: are you sure, you did modified the daemon.json correctly and stopped docker, docker.socket and container runtime containerd before making changes in daemon.json?
id not do it with following commands.

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl stop docker.socket
sudo systemctl stop containerd
```

Comment: @MichealChoudhary it is using the old directory because i have returned configuration. the problem is that ```docker container ls```, ```docker images``` is returning nothing. I haven't stopped containerd, to be honest. Shall I restart it?

Comment: Got the same issue here. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this yesterday and found this post and one other; not fully answered. Using information gleaned from [another post](https://forums.docker.com/t/error-starting-container-after-moving-docker-root-directory/64324), I've discovered to complete the solution one needs to update each `config.v2.json` inside each docker ID subdirectory (`/mnt/disk/docker/containers/*/config.v2.json`) with the new path as well to the new location. I used `perl` but one can use `sed` or whatever is your favourite utility to search and replace within multiple files. Then docker saw the moved images in the new location.

The complete process (adapted) looks like the follows:

```
(optional if you use compose)
sudo docker compose stop

sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl stop docker.socket
sudo systemctl stop containerd

sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json
(add/create the below lines in daemon.json)

{
    "data-root": "/mnt/disk/docker"
}

sudo mv -f /var/lib/docker /mnt/disk/

sudo perl -pi -e 's%/var/lib/docker%/mnt/disk/docker%g' `find /mnt/disk/docker -name "config.v2.json"`
(update all config.v2.json files in moved images)

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start containerd
sudo systemctl start docker.socket
sudo systemctl start docker

sudo docker images
(should show moved images)

sudo docker compose up -d
(optional)
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker maybe using old root directory

Validate the new Docker root location by executing following command:
`docker info -f '{{ .DockerRootDir}}'`

if the result is path of old directory, then you did something wrong. Please go through the steps to relocate the Docker root directory again and dont forget to stop docker, docker.socket and container runtime containerd :

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo systemctl stop docker.socket
sudo systemctl stop containerd
```

Comment: I tried to restart a containerd but it didn't helped. ```docker images``` is returning nothing```docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE``` but i had a several images before changes

Comment: @MeowMeow is it showing the new path, when you execute the above command ?

Comment: can you share the permission of the destination directory. maybe that is a issue.

Comment: Bad command. `docker info -f '{{ .DockerRootDir}}' –` returns `"docker info" accepts no arguments.
See 'docker info --help'.`