# docker insecure registry daemon not using flag

Tags: ubuntu, service, docker, certificate, docker-registry

I have an insecure registry running at `testcluster.myurl.name:18079`

a `docker login testcluster.myurl.name:18079` fails with no valid certificate found and suggests to specify the `--insecure-registry` flag for the daemon.

However, I already specified the flag (on Ubuntu) in `/etc/default/docker`
my

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --insecure-registry testcluster.myurl.name:18079"
```

are set and the daemon was restarted. Still the problem remains.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you running? the `/etc/default/docker` file is only used on systems using "upstart", not on systems using systemd (Ubuntu 15.04 and up)

Comment: In that case you should follow the instructions for how to use systemd "drop-ins" to configure daemon options. see the documentation here; https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. The login succeeds now. But a push ´sudo docker push testcluster.myurl.name:18079/image:version` fails with x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker daemon flags ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127580/docker-daemon-flags-ignored)